# Total no. of words formed by 2 vowels and 3 consonants taken from 4 vowels and 5 consonants is equal to?

Tags: combinatorics

```
Total no. of words formed by 2 vowels and 3 consonants taken from 4 vowels and 5      consonants is equal to ?
```

Ans. could be 1)60 2)120 3)7200 4)none
I solved it like as these 2 events don't relate to each other hence calculate them separately.
So 4C2 x 3C5 = 60 . Is it right?

Comment: Precisely.  That is correct.

Comment: The product above is correct, but the answer is wrong.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose the consonants: ${5 \choose 3} = 10$.

Choose the vowels:  ${4 \choose 2} = 6$.

Choose what order they appear in:  $5! = 120$.

That gives $7200$.

Comment: oh..I see my mistake . Thanks.

Comment: does this include a word of the form xxxxx?

Comment: @user66081 It's a vague question.  It's not an unreasonable assumption to say that all of the letters are different.  If duplicate letters were a concern, there should have been a "cannot be determined" choice, not "none (of the above)."

Comment: sounds feasible.